# Remove GCC optimizations

Tags: ros, gdb, cmake, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm trying to debug an issue with some code via GDB, but some values are apparently optimized away. How can I disable compiler optimization in CMakeLists.txt? I tried doing `rosbuild_remove_compiler_flags(my_executable "-O2")` and then `rosbuild_add_compiler_flags(my_executable "-O0")` but this doesn't appear to have done anything, according to the output of `make VERBOSE=1` it's still using -O2. What am I doing wrong? (the correct answer is trying to debug a ROS node using GDB, clearly...)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10968/remove-gcc-optimizations/) by [Ibrahim](https://answers.ros.org/users/331/ibrahim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 307 on 2011-08-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you open the CMakeLists.txt file generated by roscreate-pkg, it should contain the following lines:

```
# Set the build type.  Options are:
#  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage
#  Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization
#  Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries
#set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)
```

Just uncomment the line `set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)` and set it to

```
set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7